# How to close previously opened connections? MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I accidentally removed the C# line that used to perform the "close" method with the opened connection. Now MySQL tells me that "too many connections" has been opened. **I CAN'T ACCESS IT**

What should I do!?

Comment: Are you talking about connections that are still open on MySQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some useful information if you can get a manual connection to the server, to manage things like this in the future:

SHOW PROCESSLIST will tell you what connections are still open: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

KILL will allow you to destroy said connections: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/kill.html